# Creating an environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

I'm trying to create an environment. The code below performs something similar to what I want. My difficulty is in adjusting the content that will stay within the environment. I would like to reduce the width of the text and have the side line accompany the entire environment even though the environment occupies more than one page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ENVIROMENT  %%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}
\newenvironment{my}
{%
\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=black, text=white, inner sep=6pt] (a) {\textbf{{\large Exemplo \themycounter}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,color=black](a.north west)--($(a.north west)+(0,-20)$);
\end{tikzpicture}\vspace{-19cm}
}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{my}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{my}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may be looking for `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a hammersledge for that. Here is a proposition based on the `leftbar` environment, from the `framed` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=3cm, hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ENVIRONMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newenvironment{mine}%
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}\refstepcounter{mycounter}\leftbar\hspace*{-\dimexpr\parindent+15pt} \colorbox{black}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily Ejemplo \themycounter}\smallskip\par\noindent}%
{\endleftbar}

\begin{document}

\begin{mine}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{mine}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. My first attempt is to always use tikz, but knowing that it is not always the best thing to do. You can adjust this environment to work like this: `\befin​​{mine}[Important Example]` , and the text between `[ ]` exits on the first line along with the word **Example**?

Comment: @MarceloRodrigues: Iʹm not sure I understand quite well what you mean. Having an optional argument for the environment,  to be used in the place of `Example` + `counter`?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mine}[2][]{
    enhanced, breakable,
    title={Ejemplo~\thetcbcounter: #2}, 
    colbacktitle=black, coltitle=white, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    frame hidden, colback=white,
    attach boxed title to top left,
    boxed title style={sharp corners, size=fbox},
    sharp corners,
    left=3mm, boxsep=0pt, right=0pt, bottom=0pt,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{black},
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mine}{}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{mine}

\begin{mine}{Very important}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mine}

\begin{mine}{Very very important}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mine}

\end{document}
```

[image]